# PostreSQL returning only specific value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got below structure:

`sample_table`

```
  code         | delivery       | end_date     | type
---------------+----------------+--------------+------
C086000-T10001 | OK             | 2014-11-12   | 01
C086000-T10001 | OK             | 2014-11-11   | 03
C086000-T10002 | FALSE          | 2014-12-10   | 03
C086000-T10002 | FALSE          | 2014-01-04   | 03
C086000-T10003 | FALSE          | 2014-02-28   | 03
C086000-T10003 | FALSE          | 2014-11-12   | 01
C086000-T10003 | FALSE          | 2014-08-20   | 01
```

I want to output how many code (counted) has the OK delivery status.
I was trying to do something like:

```
SELECT sample_table.code AS code, sample_table.delivery AS delivered
FROM sample_table
WHERE COUNT(sample_table.delivery = "OK")
GROUP BY code, delivered
```

Edit
The expected output should be like below

```
  code         | delivered      | all_type     |
---------------+----------------+--------------+
C086000-T10001 | 2              | 04           |
C086000-T10002 | 0              | 06           |
C086000-T10003 | 0              | 05           |
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Hi mr_muscle, you can't have to delivered for end_date  2014-11-12 for code T10001 as an expected result because there is only one line in the sample table with  end_date  2014-11-12 for code T10001

Comment: How do you decide which value to display in column `end_date`?

Comment: Why isn't there a record in the resultset for code `C086000-T10003`?

Comment: @GMB my mistake, updated

Comment: What is the data type of `type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, the `filter()` clause comes handy for this:

```
select 
    code,
    count(*) filter(where delivery = 'OK') delivered,
    sum(type) all_type
from sample_table
group by code
```

Comment: The filter is really handy, thanks for that! How this code should be modified to count `all_type` only for `code` with `delivery = OK` ? so in the output I should have `0` for `C086000-T10002` and `C086000-T10003` and `04` for the first code - `C086000-T10001` ?

Comment: @mr_muscle: that would be `sum(type) filter(where delivery = 'OK')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  count(*)
FROM sample_table
WHERE  sample_table.delivery = "OK"
```

If you want it by code:

```
    SELECT  code,         count(*)
    FROM sample_table
    WHERE  sample_table.delivery = "OK" 
group by code
```

Answer (score 0):

With conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT code, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN delivery = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS delivered,
  SUM(type) all_type
FROM sample_table
GROUP BY code
```